# Make a child panel top of the parent panel and all other siblings

Tags: swing, drag-and-drop, jpanel, visible

I am having one parent `JPanel` and on this i have added these components.

- First `JTable`
- Seconde `JTable`
- First Child `JPanel`

Steps I am doing now.

- I am dragging the data from one `JTable`to another `JTable`.
- Creating one runtime `JPanel` that will show the dragged data.
- Adding a `JLabel` value in runntime created `JPanel`

Reference link [DNDCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886689/why-draghandler-exportasdrag-disables-my-mousemotionlistener/5033074#5033074)

I am using `GridBayLayout` for the Parent Panel.

**Problem** -

It is hiding my runntime created JPanel under the JTable i.e runntime created JPanel is not coming top of the added First JTable.

Comment: Post some code. What LayoutManager are you using?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : Thanks, Done the required changes.

Comment: I will need to see actual code to help you: at least the code where you create your parent, its layout, add its children etc... Preferrably, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumePolet : I have solved my problem by adding that panel using add(panel,0).I Found same we can do by using layered pane and setcomponenentZindex() also.